# Text and voice channels counting

Tags: javascript, discord

```
`:speech_balloon: Channels ${message.guild.channels.filter(m => m.type === 'all'.size)}`,`[** ${message.guild.channels.filter(m => m.type === 'text').size}** ] | [** ${message.guild.channels.filter(m => m.type === 'voice').size} **]`,true)
```

I am using this to give me the count of text/voice channels, the `message.guild.channels.filter(m => m.type === 'all'.size)` doesn't work and I tried `message.guild.channels.size` but it's counting the categories too.

Answer (score 4):

Count **all** channels excluding categories:

```
message.guild.channels.filter((c) => c.type !== "category").size;
```

Count **text** channels:

```
message.guild.channels.filter((c) => c.type === "text").size;
```

Count **text** and **voice** channels:

```
message.guild.channels.filter((c) => c.type === "text" || c.type === "voice").size;
```

Next time, add the `discord.js` tag to your question ;)